# How to send an image in mail body using HTML and SQL

Tags: html, sql

```
SET @MailBody=@BodySalitation+@Bodytext+  '<br> ' + '<img src="C:\Users\kireett\Downloads\happy_birthday_cake_hd_wallpaper.jpg" />'+ @BodySignature;
```

I'm using above statement for sending image in mail body .but the image is not loading actually image is located in local area not in database

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Load an image from a SQL server?

Comment: no i need to embed a image in mail using html

Comment: But the image is stored locally on your hard drive?

Comment: yes .i want to embed local image only

Answer (score 1):

You can use  tags in your HTML code like you would in any other HTML document. The src attribute of the image tag should be the URL of the image on your web server. If you want the source of the image to be a file that is instead attached to your message, you'll need to use a special URL for the `<img>` tag's src attribute.

The src attribute should be set to the letters cid: followed by the name of the attached file (case matters). For example, if you had attached a file called big_picture.jpg, the `<img>` tag would be `<img src="cid:big_picture.jpg">`

Comment: May b u can have a look [here](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think [THIS](http://www.exclamationsoft.com/exclamationsoft/netmailbot/help/website/HTMLEmailWithEmbeddedImagesFromYourHardDrive.html) tutorial will help you which is elaborating how to send a HTML email with embedded images stored on your local hard drive